How do you log with details similar to stacktraces when using the Result pattern for handling errors?
I just switched from the traditional way of handling errors by extending the Error class and throwing those Custom Error class instances from all over the code, to now using Neverthrow to simply return Result objects.
The errors themselves are plain objects (not Error (sub)class instances), with a unique error code per kind of error.
I really like how it works, and part of the benefit of returning error objects is also performance. But I'm wondering - how can I get the level of details similar to a stack trace from normal exceptions?
How do you log those error objects without important details getting lost?
